# No orientations in info.plist file , will it be rejected?

Tags: ios

I've send my first application (iOS app for iPhone) 6 days ago and it's still waiting foe review . I recognize that in info.plist file there is no supported interface orientations selected . I forgot select one of them . Is it an rejection reason ? Additionally , technically the app is using only portrait UIO , but I have implemented orientations manually (like some words are turning right 90 degree or left) with using UIDeviceOrientation , will it be a probl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very highly doubt that your app would be rejected for something so trivial. Selecting supported orientations is just additional metadata and doesn't affect the function of your app. See this post for more:

[Xcode 4 Supported Device Orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030647/xcode-4-supported-device-orientations)

Having said that, Apple can do whatever they want. If it bothers you that much, you can always reject your own binary and resubmit it with the changes. That will probably put you at the back of the line for review, which won't matter much if you recently submitted it anyway.

Comment: I know that I can reject that binary but I don't want to wait anymore if it's not a rejection reason . Thank you for your answer . Additionally , my default.png was just black (as Xcode added automatically) , do you think it will be a problem ?

Comment: I would add a better Default.png in the next version so that your app will comport with the Apple Human Interface Guidelines, but I don't think they will reject you for it.

Comment: They approved it and as you said I'll add a default.png that looks good , thanks woz . https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stupid-balls/id578147041?ls=1&mt=8